# Animating polygon style over time in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, style, database, animation

I have a shapefile, consisting of polygons. I can join a layer to a database file, and use an attribute (database value) to "style" (color in) the polygons to give me a visual representation of the data.

But the data is different for every day, so I can look at the representation for various days but I'd like to animate the progression.

I'm using QGIS and Microsoft Access.

Comment: What GIS Software are you using?

Comment: I'm using QGIS and Microsoft Access.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with that and any other requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Time Manager Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/) to animate your polygons based on time field. Also you can refer to this [answer on how to setup the data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174568/animate-polygon-shapefile-using-qgis-time-manager?rq=1) to be used in time manager.

Comment: I setup the data in access, ID, CampID, Date, SdperHa.

Comment: I setup the data in access, ID, CampID, Date, SDperHa. SD per Hectare tells me how much grass is in a camp. Ive joined the layer (CampID) in QGIS and set a Graduated style to represent SDperHa. Then I start Timemanager, Add a layer (shapefile with polygons representing the camps), The Start Date is set to my database file_Date. Time Format%Y-%m-%d. I get it to play, but there is no visualization. What am i missing? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I think I've got it. To help anyone in the future, what I did was to join the database file with my existing shapefile map. Then i saved the Database file as a .csv with xy geometry. I had to edit the .csv file in excel to make sure the Date Format was correct. Then I saved the .csv file as a shapefile in QGIS because Timemanager only works with shapefiles. Then i edited the atribute table so that my SDperHa columb was a decimal number format. Set the style to graduated on the SDperHa layer. Then added the layer to Timemanager an it works. Hope this helps someone else looking to do something similar