# How to animate daily data in QGIS time manager plugin by changing color of polygon instead of plotting markers

Tags: qgis, visualisation, timemanager

I 'm a beginner in QGIS in general and geo spatial data visualization. 
Given a vector type map (.tab file) of districts geographically spanning my business area and csv file containing weekly sales volume per district. I tried to animate the weekly sales per district using QGIS time manager plugin.
How to animate data from the csv by changing the vector map color , instead of plotting separate colored markers ?

I expected my result would be like this :
https://underdark.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/thl_population.gif

Comment: For Time-aware QGIS with the Temporal Controller, (like QGIS 3.14) an important component of a solution is to override the `Layer/Properties/Symbology/Single Symbol/Fill Color` with a time-varying field by using the "Data defined override" boxes to the right of the data-entry box as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174568/animate-polygon-shapefile-using-qgis-time-manager/377442#377442