# Chronological sort & indexing problems with QGIS Time Manager

Tags: qgis, spatial-index, timemanager

I am trying to use QGIS Time Manager to create an animated map of property connected to polygon-geometry. The [one article on animating polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174568/animate-polygon-shapefile-using-qgis-time-manager) I've found on this site hasn't helped because my data is joined to an existing shapefile, and the spatial index (FID) of the target file is preserved, meaning it won't resort chronologically to play nicely with the Time Manager plugin.

As a result, the Time Manager does something weird where it applies an auto-filter Query to my layer's data and arbitrary zero end date of `'0001-01-01'`. I did not set an "end date", but used "Accumulate features" setting

[image: bunk auto-filter]

I have tried re-indexing using the *Add Autoincremental Field* to create a new index (with the sort condition set to Ascending on the Date field), but the FID of the new shapefile persists... Am I using the right strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data doesn't have to be sorted chronologically but TimeManager doesn't support joined fields. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/148).

You'll need to export the joined layer to create a new dataset that can then be manged by TimeManager.

Comment: So I tried exporting the joined CSV table as a new file, as both a shapefile and a geopakage, and encountered the same issue. Thoughts?

Comment: In the screenshot 0001-01-01 is the start and 2005-01-01 is the end date. That looks ok to me.

Comment: Thank you!!! Once I stopped hitting my head against the wall I realized I was reading it backwards, I got confused because the field set in the Query was the "earliest date"which I set in the TimeManager GUI, not the "end date", which explains why nothing was happening because it filtered out all of the data by default... I think chronologically I read left to right and would expect the beginning to be the first #, and the end to be the second #, but this could just be the novice speaking